# Extracting audio from video in Android

Tags: android, mediastore

I am creating an app that records a video.
My next step is to extract audio from that video clip and then process it. Is there a way to extract audio from a video file in `Android`. I am using `MediaStore`API for recording purposes.

Comment: I don't think if it is possible. However reverse to it, adding an audio to video ( merging ) is possible.

Comment: Its long process using NDK and LameWrapper class.

Comment: can you give me any helpful link

Comment: I would like to give you link, but i dont have any. sorry

Answer (score 0):

MediaExtractor is the one you should use.